# Use printk in kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I am trying to implement my own new `schedule()`. I want to debug my code.

Can I use `printk` function in `sched.c`?

I used `printk` but it doesn't work. What did I miss?

Answer (score 8):

Do you know how often `schedule()` is called? It's probably called faster than your computer can flush the print buffer to the log. I would suggest using another method of debugging. For instance running your kernel in QEMU and using remote GDB by loading the kernel.syms file as a symbol table and setting a breakpoint. Other virtualization software offers similar features. Or do it the manual way and walk through your code. Using printk in interrupt handlers is typically a bad idea (unless you're about to panic or stall).

If the error you are seeing doesn't happen often think of using `BUG()` or `BUG_ON(cond)` instead. These do conditional error messages and shouldn't happen as often as a non-conditional `printk`

Editing the `schedule()` function itself is typically a bad idea (unless you want to support multiple run queue's etc...). It's much better and easier to instead modify a scheduler class. Look at the code of the CFS scheduler to do this. If you want to accomplish something else I can give better advice.

Answer (score 2):

It's not safe to call printk while holding the runqueue lock. A special function `printk_sched` was introduced in order to have a mechanism to use printk when holding the runqueue lock (https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/3/13/13). Unfortunatly it can just print one message within a tick (and there cannot be more than one tick when holding the run queue lock because interrupts are disabled). This is because an internal buffer is used to save the message.

You can either use [lttng2](http://lttng.org/lttng-kernel-tracer)  for logging to user space or patch the implementation of `printk_sched` to use a statically allocated pool of buffers that can be used within a tick.

Answer (score 2):

Try `trace_printk()`.
`printk()` has too much of an overhead and `schedule()` gets called again before previous `printk()` calls finish. This creates a live lock.
Here is a good article about it: https://lwn.net/Articles/365835/

Answer (score 0):

It depends, basically it should be work fine.

try to use `dmesg` in shell to trace your `printk` if it is not there you apparently didn't invoked it.

```
2396         if (p->mm && printk_ratelimit()) {
2397                 printk(KERN_INFO "process %d (%s) no longer affine to cpu%d\n",
2398                                 task_pid_nr(p), p->comm, cpu);
2399         }
2400 
2401         return dest_cpu;
2402 }
```

there is a sections in `sched.c` that `printk` doesn't work e.g.

```
1660 static int double_lock_balance(struct rq *this_rq, struct rq *busiest)
1661 {
1662         if (unlikely(!irqs_disabled())) {
1663                 /* printk() doesn't work good under rq->lock */
1664                 raw_spin_unlock(&this_rq->lock);
1665                 BUG_ON(1);
1666         }
1667 
1668         return _double_lock_balance(this_rq, busiest);
1669 }
```

### **EDIT**

you may try to `printk` once in 1000 times instead of each time.

Comment: printk can stall waiting for a flush which is a bad thing, I would avoid calling it unconditionally in schedule

Comment: Does he? or does he mean he tried to modify the schedule function? I would think replacing it would be pretty bad. And why he didn't just edit a scheduler instead is beyond me.

Comment: @JesusRamos can you suggest in your answer what you would edit?